# How to add a menu button to layout (template) form in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to add a  [menu button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Isbi1.png) (3 horizontal lines) to the right of my Layout form , so that it will be not responsive (visible at the normal resolution 100% of my PC browser 1366 x 768 without zoomig or unzooming), but I don't know how with the Bootstrap United theme.

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Here is my HTML page :

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - BEMF Revues</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    @Html.ActionLink("BEMF Revues", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
                </div>
                <div id="navbarCollapse" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="dropdown active">


                            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Revues<span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Support de demande</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Support de revue</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Tableau de suivi</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Support de contacts</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Ticket OTRS</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("À propos", "About", "Home")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                    </ul>
                    <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Rechercher">
                            <div class="input-group-btn">
                                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
                                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"><li><a href="#">Messages <span class="badge">0</span></a></li></ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-text navbar-right">Bonjour, @Environment.UserName</ul>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - BEMF Revues</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always create a right-aligned (navbar-right) drop-down (dropdown, dropdown-toggle, dropdown-menu) menu with a hamburger glyph (glyphicon-menu-hamburger) in it.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/naveeninja/7a9f3d8k/1/)

[image: Reference image]